# Comparing strings in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, compare

I have a program that reads student names and grades line by line from a .txt file using fgets and a buffer declared as:

```
char buffer[1024];
```

Now the file should end with the string "end" on a line all by itself.

How do I tell a while loop to terminate when `buffer == "end"`?

I tried using `strcmp` but it segfaults for some reason.

Comment: `strcmp` is the right function to use, it must be something else.

Comment: Is this homework? Can we see your code?

Comment: You should figure out why `strcmp` segfaults rather than avoiding the issue.

Comment: The code is very involved, as the assignment is complete. It's just that I can't put "end" at the end of the file because that will cause a segfault. I just need a way to use "end" as a means of stopping reading, because as of now I'm using "fgets(buffer, 1024, file) != NULL" to kick out of reading.

Comment: Please post the broken strcmp code which is segfaulting.

Comment: Post the skeleton code for file reading loop, with the strcmp.

Comment: Alright guys I got it, all I needed to do was use strncpr and specify the number of characters that need comparing. it still segfaults, but it produces the correct output.

Comment: If your code still segfaults, you haven't "got it".

Comment: @AJ_507: Does the assignment require you to use `"end"` to mark the end of the data? If not, it's probably better to check for end-of-file.

Comment: Would you willing to post the line on which you expect to find an "end"?

Answer (score 4):

To simply answer your question, strcmp actually *is* the function you're looking for:

```
#include <string.h>

if(!strcmp(line, "end\n") || !strcmp(line, "end\r\n"))
    break;
```

or similar should do the trick. Note the `!` in front of strcmp as strcmp returns 0 (i.e. false) if the strings match. But I guess you already know that since you've already mentioned strcmp in your question.

On the segfault issue: Are you sure none of the pointers you pass to strcmp are NULL? Most C standard libraries don't do any error checking here and will run into segfaults when trying to read the memory at `*(0)`.

Another possible issue that pops into my mind is that using strcmp will of course only work if you've already split your buffer into an array of single strings. `strtok_r` is probably most suited for this task (Altough [quite tricky](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/strtok_r.3.asp) to use).

Comment: The second test with `\r` is unnecessary; if you read in text mode, then OS-specific line endings are translated to `'\n'`.

Comment: @KeithThompson: I don't think that's safe to assume. On any POSIX system there is only one way to open a file using the C standard library (`fopen`) and it specifically says in the standard that `r` and `rb` are identical modes.

Comment: Yes, because POSIX text files use *only* `'\n'` to terminate lines. On Windows, for example, `"r"` and `"rb"` are distinct; `"r"` translates `\r\n` to `\n`, and `"rb"` doesn't. Things get tricky when you're reading files in a foreign text format, but I don't think the OP needs to worry about that.

Comment: @KeithThompson: If the file was given to him as part of an assignment then it's not safe to assume either line ending. Having a `.txt` extension smells like Windows since its rare for text files to have any sort of extension on POSIX systems, which may be what the OP is using. Without knowing the file format or the host environment it is safer to search for both `\n` and `\r\n`.

Comment: @dreamlax: It's hardly likely that an introductory-level assignment like this would require the student to worry about line endings, and we have no indication that the assignment mentioned the issue at all.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use formatted IO when the format of the text in the file is fixed and use !EOF for looping?

For example:

```
while(fp!=EOF)
{    fscanf(fp,"%s %s %d",name,grades, &marks);
     printf("Name: %s\tGrade: %s\t Marks: %d\n",name,grade,marks);
}
```

This would automatically detect the end of file, which would also remove the condition of having a string 'end' in the text file.

Comment: This is terrible, why is it upvoted? Who told you that `fp != EOF` is correct? Also, read the manual or documentation for `fscanf()`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `strncmp(buffer, "end", 3)` to compare the first three characters along with `if(3 == strlen(buffer)` to make sure end does not start the line, should solve the problem.

Comment: If that helps, it's because he's forgetting about the `'\n'`. It's better to deal with the `'\n'` directly. Using `strncmp(line, "end", 3")` also creates false positive results for lines *starting* with \"end"\.

Comment: @KeithThompson I'm confused about the original post, then, because it looks like end is to appear on a line all by itself.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus: The point is that `strncmp(buffer, "end", 3)` will incorrectly indicate a match on a line consisting of `"endurance"`.

Answer (score 0):

char *fgets(char *restrict s, int n, FILE *restrict stream);

The  fgets()  function shall read bytes from stream into the array pointed to by s, until n-1 bytes are read, or a  is read and transferred to s, or an end-of-file condition is encountered. The string is then  terminated with a null byte.

so, when you read string "end", the element in buffer should be {'e', 'n', 'd', '\n', '\0'}, you can using strcmp as follows:

```
size_t len = strlen(buffer);
if (buffer[len - 1] == '\n')
{
    buffer[len - 1] == '\0';
}

if (strcmp(buffer, "end") == 0)
{
    //end
}
```

or

```
if (strncmp(buffer, "end", 3) == 0)
{
    //end
}
```